# "no field on type" error with generic type implementations

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to make a project but I can't make progress due to an error that keeps popping up. I've tried to abstract it to give you a simpler example. Can anyone tell me why, in the `get_value` function, within the implementation for `Element`, it is not possible to get the values of the `Element`. It should, right? Since I'm explicitly saying the implementation is for Element...

```rust
struct Element<T> {
    value: T,
}

trait HasValue<T> {
    fn get_value(&self) -> T;
}

impl<Element> HasValue<Element> for Element {
    fn get_value(&self) -> Element {
        self.value // Error!
    }
}
```

```
error[E0609]: no field `value` on type `&Element`
  --> src/lib.rs:11:14
   |
9  | impl<Element> HasValue<Element> for Element {
   |      ------- type parameter 'Element' declared here
10 |     fn get_value(&self) -> Element {
11 |         self.value // Error!
   |              ^^^^^
```

Comment: Remove the first `<Element>` in the impl. I.e. `impl HasValue<Element> for Element { … }`

Comment: Please always post the errors from `cargo check`.

Answer (score 4):

***`Element` is not `Element`***. That is, this `Element`:

```rust
struct Element<T> {
//     ^^^^^^^
```

Is not the same as these `Element`s:

```rust
impl<Element> HasValue<Element> for Element {
//   ^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^
    fn get_value(&self) -> Element {
    //                     ^^^^^^^
```

The first is a concrete (well, generic) struct with the name `Element`.  The second is a generic parameter with the name `Element`, that can be the struct `Element` but can also be any other type, such as `i32` or `String`. You can rename either without affecting the other.

The generic parameter *shadows* the struct because it has the same name, and within the `impl` `Element` will refer to it and not the struct. Because it can be any type, it doesn't necessarily have a `value` field - and thus the compiler is complaining.

I suppose what you actually want is not "for any type", but "for any `Element<T>` type". That is, only `T` should be generic, not the type itself. To express that you should write:

```rust
impl<T> HasValue<T> for Element<T> {
    fn get_value(&self) -> T {
        self.value
    }
}
```

Now you'll get another error because you're moving `self.value`, but that is a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles, either using generics:

```
struct Element<T: Copy> {
    value: T,
}

trait HasValue<T>{
    fn get_value(&self) -> T;
}

impl<T: Copy> HasValue<T> for Element<T> {
    fn get_value(&self) -> T {
        self.value
    }
}
```

or with concrete types:

```
struct Element<T> {
    value: T,
}

trait HasValue<T>{
    fn get_value(&self) -> T;
}

impl HasValue<String> for Element<String> {
    fn get_value(&self) -> String {
        self.value.clone().replace("t", "est")
    }
}

impl HasValue<u64> for Element<u64> {
    fn get_value(&self) -> u64 {
        self.value
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to do a diferent implementation for every tipe of "T", how can I do that?